# Change the Grid View Pages on button click in C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem that I want to change the Grid View page on button click. Means Grid View paging concept on button click in C#. I have to click on a button having a particular number text, then this will shows the particular page of gridview corresponding to the Button clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have implemented the paging concept in Gridview and searched on web to implement it on button click but nothing finds related to that. That's why I asked a question on the web. And I also comment on many questions as you. But after search regarding that.

Comment: @Shai Means? Is it related to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PageIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindex.aspx) property for that.